# Logback - Logging multiple levels to one file

Tags: java, logging, logback

I need to create a file that only logs TRACE and DEBUG events, but I'm unable to make it work (don't know if it's even possible).

Already tried searching for an option to invert the ThresholdFilter or a way to specify multiple levels on a LevelFilter, but with no success.

The only way that I'm thinking to make this work is to create 2 appende, exactly the same from one to another, but with the LevelFilter in one specified to TRACE and the other to DEBUG.

Is there any other way to accomplish this? Because I'm not a big fan of duplicating code/configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple approach might be to create custom filter as below.

```
public class CustomFilter extends Filter<ILoggingEvent> {

    private String levels;

    public String getLevels() {
        return levels;
    }

    public void setLevels(String levels) {
        this.levels = levels;
    }

    private Level[] level;

    @Override
    public FilterReply decide(ILoggingEvent arg0) {

        if (level == null && levels != null) {
            setLevels();
        }
        if (level != null) {
            for (Level lev : level) {
                if (lev == arg0.getLevel()) {
                    return FilterReply.ACCEPT;
                }
            }
        }

        return FilterReply.DENY;
    }

    private void setLevels() {

        if (!levels.isEmpty()) {
            level = new Level[levels.split("\\|").length];
            int i = 0;
            for (String str : levels.split("\\|")) {
                level[i] = Level.valueOf(str);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add filter in logback.xml

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="fileAppender1" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <filter class="com.swasthik.kp.logback.filters.CustomFilter">
            <levels>TRACE|DEBUG</levels>
        </filter>
        <file>c:/logs/kplogback.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="TRACE">
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender1" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```